# Реализация strncmp для вектора на итераторах

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, stl, сравнение, вектор

Дано:

Строка: `S1` - начало вектора, `S2` - конец вектора(`std::next(S2)` - будет `end()` вектора)

Подстрока: `R1` - начало вектора, `R2` - конец вектора(`std::next(R2)` - будет `end()` вектора) 

Позиция: `pos` 

Команда: strncmp(Строка, Подстрока, Позиция);

Нужно сделать аналог *СИ*шного [strncmp](http://cppstudio.com/post/715/), только возвращающего true/false

---

Получил что-то типа:

```
bool boyerMoore::TextCompare(аргументы см. выше){

    return std::equal(
                R1,
                std::next(R2),
                std::distance(S1, pos));

}
```

Но не уверен, что это верно....

Comment: что за типы у s1, s2 r1, r2? что вообще за "аргументы см. выше" , влом записать нормально?

Comment: S1,S2,R1,R2 - это std::vector<BYTE>::iterator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, сверхзадача примерно такая: есть вектор (контейнер) v1 и v2, и надо убедиться, что n элементов первого, начиная с какого-то i-го, равны n же элементам второго, начиная с какого-то j-го.

Если да - то не надо дополнительные фокусы, просто вызывайте стандартный алгоритм [`equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) явно.

Например, сравнение 10 элементов v1, начиная с первого, и v2, начиная с третьего, будут иметь вид

```
equal(v1.begin()+1, v1.begin()+11, v2.begin()+3);
```

Вам не надо передавать конец "подстроки" или "позицию" (ее смысл совершенно неясен) - число сравниваемых элементов определяется первым диапазоном.

Еще - конец диапазона определяется итератором **за** концом диапазона.

И еще - к алгоритму Боера-Мура алгоритм `equal` не имеет никакого отношения...

Comment: Только писать четко количество - не гуд, лучше использовать дистанс

Comment: Если контейнер вообще - да, если вектор - без проблем и так.